# Unable to pass intent value to next activity

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing an issue to pass intent values to next activity.

While creating profile I created two databasereferences **1.** with pushid **2.** without push id

Now I am trying to pass values from databaseref with pushid

My code looks like this

```
        mDatabaseReference = mDatabase!!.reference.child("Tokens").child(userId).push()
```

to store push id key value, i used variable like below one

```
        var tokenID: String = mDatabaseReference!!.key!!
```

to push this value to intent, I used

```
        intent.putExtra(TOKENID,tokenID)
```

when I used log I can see push id value

TOKENID I created at initial activity with companion object

To pass this push id value to next activity

```
        tokenreq = intent.getStringExtra(Profile.TOKENID)
```

to retreive values i used below databasereference

```
mDatabaseReference = mDatabase!!.reference.child("Tokens").child(userId).child(tokenreq!!)
```

when I run the program, app crash mentioning KotlinNullPointerException for tokenreq in log data

log file

```
    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at com.luvpi.luvproject.activities.Verification$onCreate$2.onClick(Verification.kt:96)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22288)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

complete code for process

```
            checkcode.setOnClickListener {
            val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid

            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

            Log.d(TAG,"Push id is $tokenrequest")

            mDatabaseReference = mDatabase!!.reference.child("Tokens").child(userId).child(tokenrequest!!)


            mDatabaseReference!!.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
                override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                }

                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                    var tokenkey = dataSnapshot.child("tokenid").value.toString()

                    Log.d(TAG,"Verification Code is $tokenkey")

                    if (tokenkey == userverify.toString()) {

                        Toast.makeText(this@Verification, "Successfully Verified", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show()
                        startActivity(Intent(this@Verification, LatestMessage::class.java))
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this@Verification, "Verification code is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        return
                    }
                }

            })

        }
```

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: There might be problem of TOKENID

Comment: I would check tokenID value right before calling intent.putExtra(TOKENID,tokenID) instruction

Comment: Please add the entire error and the line at which it occurs.

Comment: attached log info

Answer (score 0):

Your reqToken is not child. It should be value. So you should use this for mDatabaseReference;

```
mDatabaseReference = mDatabase!!.reference.child("Tokens").child(userId)
```

Second step;

```
mDatabaseReference.setValue(reqToken)
```

Third step;

```
val valueEventListenerUser2 = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        var tokenreq = dataSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)!!
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
    }
}
mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListenerUser2)
```

Comment: .get(tokenreq) is not picking up and also defined datasnapshot but push id cannot be retrieved

Comment: Can you see push id from firebase? I mean did you check your value push firebase? You should use this code for push value; 

mDatabase!!.reference.child("Tokens").child(userId).setValue(tokenreq)

Comment: i am getting push id in profile activity and in database separate Token parent is created but next activity still displaying null pointer and updated info. i tried ur method still getting same info attached log info